# Expected string or bytes-like object in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, python-re

I am trying to iterate over the list 'companies' to find the tuple that contains 'VIC' in the 5th element of it. However, i get the following error:

'expected string or bytes-like object'

I know this error is due to the unfinished bracket in the last tuple of the list. How would I fix this? (The companies list is from a large dataset)

What should I do to remedy this?

```
merchant_state = 'VIC'

companies = [(378355, 'ACT', 'DEJAN TOMIC', 'Individual/Sole Trader', 
'VIC', '3175', 97603461250, 'FADEDLINESBARBERSHOP', 20), 
(408649, 'ACT', 'ALEXANDER DEJANOVIC', 
'Individual/Sole Trader', 'NSW', '2193', 97733511621, None, 20),
(433402, 'ACT', 'LUTHERAN CHURCH OF AUSTRALIA QUEENSLAND DISTRICT(LUTHERAN COMM CAR', 'Other Unincorporated Entity', 'QLD', '4560', 97899426696, 'GRACEVILLE CENTRE', 20)]

companies = [item for item in companies if re.search(item[4],merchant_state, re.IGNORECASE ) != -1]
```

Comment: You are parsing ints, which re does not handle.

Comment: You error cannot be reproduced with the data here, maybe in your actual data there is a non-string in `item[4]`, we cannot know. Note, the code is not working the way you expect regardless of the error `if re.search(item[4],merchant_state, re.IGNORECASE ) != 1` should jsut be `if re.search(item[4],merchant_state, re.IGNORECASE ) != -1` because `re.search` never returns `-1` or any interger for that matter, it returns a `re.Match` object or `None`, hence oyu can filter on the truthiness

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. You're correct. I have amended my question now to reflect this.

Comment: Your edit *did not address this at all*. The code **still doesn't throw any errors**. It also isn't clear what you mean by "I know this error is due to the unfinished bracket in the last tuple of the list. How would I fix this? (The companies list is from a large dataset)" ... *there is no unfinished bracket*, it isn't clear what you mean, unless you are referring the parentheses in the `str`, but why would that affect anything at all?

Comment: Note that the error indicates that the *second* argument to ``re.search`` is of the wrong type. That would be ``merchant_state``, not ``item[4]``.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the given data; the problem clearly has nothing to do with list comprehensions; and the unmatched `(` is inside a string, so that will not matter. Voting to close.

Answer (score -1):

List comprehension loops through the list sequence `--but doesn't change or delete any elements in it--`. I think what you want is `filter(fun, seq)`. For simplicity, you can filter on all 4th index equal to VIC.

```
companies = filter(lambda r: r[4] == 'VIC', companies)

print(companies) # this will print <filter object at 0x....> because it's lazy invoked

for i in companies:
    print(i)
```

Edit: I stand corrected, list comprehension CAN filter.

Comment: Comprehensions are suitable for filtering - that is what their if clause is there for.

Comment: List comprehensions *absolutely can filter a list*, the whole point is to be able to do mapping/filtering operations

Comment: This doesn't explain the OP's error, which isn't reproducible

Comment: I'm sure 2to3 replaces filters with lists of lists - what is the rationale for 2to3 recommending the latter? Is it somehow preferred in python3?

Comment: Anyway, the error is nothing to do with this